# Cannot recover Berkeley DB environment

Tags: c++, berkeley-db

When I try to a recovery over a Berkeley DB environment home, with this C++ code:

```
auto envFlags = DB_CREATE       |
                DB_INIT_LOCK    |
                DB_INIT_LOG     |
                DB_INIT_MPOOL   |
                DB_INIT_TXN     |
                DB_THREAD       |
                DB_RECOVER;

dbEnv.open(dbHomePath.c_str(), envFlags, 0);
```

I get the following error:

```
BDB1579 Database handles still open at environment close
```

What could this be?

Comment: What did you do with `dbEnv` before this call? The error gets generated, when the reference count of the handle (`db_ref`) is not zero, i.e.when you already opened/created a database with that environment.

Comment: @dhke How do I obtain the reference count? I'm not doing anything before with the environment.